# how to know when to release string for iphone

Tags: iphone

i have this

```
 NSXMLParser *xmlParserf = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //  NSLog(@"URL%@",urlf);
    //Initialize the delegate.

    XMLParser *parserf = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    [xmlParserf setDelegate:parserf];

    //Start parsing the XML file.

    BOOL successs = [xmlParserf parse];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSLog(@" this xml  is %d",[xmlParserf retainCount]);// getting error
    NSLog(@" this paaat is %d",[parserf retainCount]);// getting error

    if(successs)
    {
        NSLog(@"ZONE IS PARSED");
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NOT PARSED!!!");
    }

    //[xmlParserf release]; not working
            //[parserf release];
```

now i dont know when to release those objects these are running in some threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everytime you `alloc` (or `copy`), you must either `release` or `autorelease`.

In this case:

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParserf = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
```

and

```
XMLParser *parserf = [[[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser] autorelease];
```

It means that you keep it in memory at least until the end of the current function. If other objects hang on to it (i.e. `retain` it) then the objects stay in memory, until they are `released` (by those other objects).